# validate zipcode of every country for namecheap api

Tags: php, validation, pattern-matching, zipcode

I am trying to make a domain registration script using the namecheap api. everything is ok except for the zipcode validation. After testing it I found out that namecheap validates zipcodes even thought it doesnt say in their documentation. I got an error like this:

```
Zipcode was invalid for that country. Sample format: 22165
```

I tried with 4 digits zip code and I got this error. Now the first thing that comes in to my mind is that I have to validate the zip code for all countries of the world and it will take a lot of time to find reliable resources for each country zipcode format plus they have different patterns meaning a lot of programming! Since I didn't find anything by searching google, I would like to know if anyone faced this problem before, or has a better idea to solve this?

Here is their documentation page for domain registration: 
https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/methods/domains/create.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to mind:

1. Just handle their error message and return it to the user. In other words, let NameCheap do their own data validation and you just handle their error messages so the user can fix any problems. This might be the easiest.
2. If you want to validate postal codes yourself, a simple Google search for [country postal code formats](https://www.google.com/search?q=country%20postal%20code%20formats) yielded some [useful](http://www.geopostcodes.com/resources) [results](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes). (What did you search for that nothing came up?)

Comment: for the first option yes I can do that but the domain need to be registered after the payment is made, in this situation the client will pay for the domain and then an error will come up that domain was not registered because of the zipcode. After searching google I found out that I have to do a lot of work to validate the zipcodes before the payment and I also found out that even some namecheap clients had problems with these errors and then namecheap replied that the error was fixed etc..